# trying to understand Java activities by following a book

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

I am new to programming and I am trying to figure out how Activities in android programming work by making a small app,which should let me know in which state of the activity I am.

I am getting an error in the setContentView because Android Studio says "cannot resolve symbol "R""

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.daniele.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String tag = "Lifecycle";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d(tag, "in the onCreate() event");
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(tag, "in the onStart() event");
    }

    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d(tag, "in the onRestart() event");
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(tag, "in the onResume() event");
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(tag, "in the onPause() event");
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(tag, "in the onStop() event");
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(tag, "in the onDestroy() event");
    }
}
```

here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.daniele.activity" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: In Android Studio try Build -> Clear Project

Comment: You could also try Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files. If that fails then you could try Build -> Rebuild Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone is suggesting you the fix. Good. But since you are learning, you should also understand what is happening here:

- All layout files are in xml
- Every xml file is compiled and made available to java classes
- The compiled class is called R.java
- To make
  R.java available to your class you need to import it

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but when I try to import it with import com.example.daniele.R i'm getting the "unused import statement error"

Comment: This is just wrong.  To see why, open R.java and take a look!  It is not complied layout.  It's just static constants to all resources in the app,

Comment: Oh then I think guys uploading videos from sanfran are wrong

Answer (score 0):

Under

```
import android.util.Log;
```

add this

```
import com.example.daniele.R;
```

Alternatively when you see a red underline under something, you can hover above it and Android Studio usually tells you what you need to do. In this case, "Optimize Imports" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

"R" errors usually happen when one or more of your XML files is corrupt. Start by seeing if your apps manifest looks correct!

Comment: please look at it.. i'm no expert :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import R because your activity is in a different package.

```
import com.example.daniele.R;
```

Comment: Maybe the question has been edited, but the activity is in the same package declared in the manifest: `com.example.daniele.activity`.  It should not require an import statement.